# Git bare repo - /refs/head/master deleted - How to get last commit id?

Tags: git

I have a bare repository.

For unknown reasons the `/refs/head/master` file got deleted.

Because I don't know the id of the latest commit, **I wonder how can I recover it so that I can recreate the master file** (holding the id).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `git reflog` to find where your HEAD has been.

Note the hash of the appropriate commit and do `git branch master <hash>`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer: I am getting `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`

Comment: It sounds to me like your repository is badly damaged. Was more than `/refs/head/master` deleted in it?

Comment: @ValentinDespa: Instead of using `HEAD` use its SHA-1 id to branch.

Comment: The bare repo had the logs not enabled => reflog in this case was empty. I've managed to recover it by finding the commit it from the latest client that made a commit. Thanks again for your help.